# Is it permitted for a couple to have relations during the daytime?

Tags: halacha, sexuality, daytime

Is it permitted for couples to have relations in the daytime if they are tired in the evenings?

Comment: Why is the assumption that they can't? That may make this a better question.

Comment: Is it permitted to have relations in the evening if they are tired in the day? What if they had chicken for dinner? But what if it's partly cloudy?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22092

Comment: ....keep in mind that Mi Yodeya is not really a place for practical halachic advice -- any information you get here should be [treated as if it came from a crowd of your friends](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)....

Comment: @DoubleAA But what if the husband is a Talmid Chachamim, or the house is dark, or the person has an insatiable urge, or, or, or... there are all kinds of strange exception and leniencies in Judaism - you'll never know unless you ask.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes I'm not sure what you are trying to say. The question is a poor one for the reasons we both describe: it has no motivation so it sounds just like asking any of our questions which are equally poor.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm trying to say make your criticism constructive and phrase it in such a way that it encourages better questions, and doesn't sound like you're making fun of the person.  Andrew's comment is constructive without coming across as snarky.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes Surprisingly, most people don't get it from a comment like andrew's without seeing extremes. It's apparently hard to realize that not everyone can know what you are thinking.

Answer (score 6):

We learn in Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 240:11 [סימן רמ - איך יתנהג האדם בתשמיש מטתו](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_24.html#HtmpReportNum0000_L2):

> אָסוּר לְשַׁמֵּשׁ בַּיּוֹם, אֶלָּא אִם כֵּן הוּא בַּיִת אָפֵל

One is forbidden to have relations during the day unless it's a dark room.

From this we see that **in a darkened room you may have relations during the day**. There is no prerequisite for the daytime to be more convenient.

BTW: In Shulchan Aruch Even haEzer 25:5 סימן כה - לגדר גדר שלא להרבות בתשמיש, וכיצד [יתנהג בשעת תשמיש](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01974_part_2.html#HtmpReportNum0018_L2) we learn:

> אָסוּר לְשַׁמֵּשׁ מִטָּתוֹ בַּיּוֹם, שֶׁעַזּוּת פָּנִים הִיא לוֹ

That a person is forbidden to have relations during the day. However, there's a note there to see the Halacha in Orach Chaim.

Comment: The Talmud (Niddah 17a as understood by Rashi) praises people who, due to being tired at night and not enjoying the experience, have relations during the day time.